astro(starlight)において，あるページのheader部にmetaタグを追加したい．
（他サイトでも同じ質問をしています．）
Googleサーチコンソールで所有権の確認のため，header部分にmetaタグを追加したい．astroを使ってcloudflareでサイトを公開するので，header部分にmetaタグを追加するのが簡単と考え，ロジックを追加した．
ただ，ローカル上で確認すると，<meta>のみ追加され，肝心のnameやcontent属性が付与されない．何が誤っているのか不明で少し困っている．
期待：<meta name="google-site-verification" content="XXX">
実際：<meta>
回避策はあるので，今はそれをしている．
開発環境

nodejs : v20.15.1
astro : 4.13.0
@astrojs/starlight : 0.25.3

やったこと
index.mdxのフロントマターにheadを追加．<meta>のみ追加される．
head:
    - tag: 'meta'
      attrs: {
            name: 'google-site-verification',
            content: 'XXX'
      }


公式のドキュメントにあるサンプルで試すと，<title>が上書きされ，想定どおりとなる．
head:
  # カスタム<title>タグを使う
  - tag: title
    content: カスタムのタイトル

回避策
特定のページ（index.mdx）のみmetaタグを追加したい．全ページに追加されるこの回避策はそのうちやめたい．
astro.config.mjsのdefineConfigに以下のとおり追加．
  integrations: [starlight({
    head:[
      {
        tag:'meta',
        attrs:{
          name: 'google-site-verification',
          content: 'XXX'
        },
      },
    ],
    title: 'YYY',
    ...


(2024/8/7 対応方法がわかったので，編集．)
Edit the HTML head of Starlight pages
にheader部へのタグ追加方法が記載されていました．
個別ページに以下のとおりに追加すればよいです．
head:
  # Add a custom meta tag to define the author of this page.
  - tag: meta
    attrs:
      name: author
      content: HiDeoo

